# Does guilt and conscience come from a higher source?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, guilt

Can someone have a conscience if they never were taught what was good from bad? Could they feel guilty without the education of what was right? If so, does that mean that conscience could come from a higher source, such as God?

Comment: Psycopaths have little or no conscience and nearly all of them have been educated on the difference of right and wrong. They feel fear of being caught but not guilt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Conscience is the set of our internalized moral rules. Internalizing
   starts with our education and become socialized in our native group.
   During our life we expand and also change the content of this
   memory.
2. Lawrence Kohlberg initiated the scientific study of the individual
   moral development, for an introduction see [stages of moral
   development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg%27s_stages_of_moral_development). Possibly Sigmund Freud was the first who equated
   the conscience with the moral rules we have internalized from our
   education. He called it the Super-Ego (German: Ueber-Ich).

   Many Jews and Christians consider their God Jahwe as the universal
   law giver and educate also their children in their belief.
   Non-theistic person do not share this belief and explain moral from
   other sources, e.g., as a means to stabilize the society and to facilitate living with my neighbours.
3. Socialization in a given social group is necessary for the personal
   development of every human. Therefore I’m in doubt that children
   can grow up without any teaching about right and wrong.

Comment: I heard from someone today saying it appears that many people have no clue of any sort of moral ideas. They are pre-preconventional. Perhaps this is just in the USA, where we seem to get by without frilly things like that.

Answer (score 2):

**ADDED (4/2/2024):**

Yes. If the biological ego is the effort to govern action in the world, and if the biological ego generates feelings of desire, pleasure, pain, and ideas of cause, as described by Baruch Spinoza, then the biological ego experiences guilt in the context of persistent pain with the idea of the self as the cause. This could occur in the absence of social interaction and would be the basis for understanding the psychological concept of abandonment trauma. All emotions are essentially non-verbal and preverbal in origin and the capacity for introspection and language enable us to discuss emotions. The ability to reason about causes and consequences would be lacking cognitive meaning in the absence of emotions as described by Spinoza.

There is no need to learn the meaning of guilt except in the social context where we discuss and describe guilt and/or the concept of a guilty conscience. One does not have to be punished or disciplined by an authority figure to feel guilt one only has to feel pain and blame the self. But since we would almost certainly die during early life in the absence of social interaction the moral feelings of blame and guilt are woven into social memories by necessity as social animals with emotions and moral judgments.

**ORIGINAL**

Baruch Spinoza describes an affect (emotion) as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. If there are no patterns of feeling and ideas of moral cause then there is no cognitive means to recognize right or wrong actions or good or bad outcomes. Humans would be indifferent to the actions of self and others, and to the perception of outcomes, if we had no such emotions, as described by Spinoza.

Philosophers have not, in general, made a sophisticated cognitive evaluation of stories in scripture such as the story of the first man and woman eating the fruit of the tree of knowledge of good and evil. The story says the woman is innocent or lacking the knowledge of good and evil. Yet she sees that the fruit of knowledge is good for eating. So before eating the fruit she already has the cognitive capacity to observe the fruit and evaluate it as good to eat! To decode the story one must contemplate its meaning in the context of one's own affective emotional states.

If there is a biological drive to sustain vitality, the ability to live, and to avoid suffering with persistent pain, then that is all that is required to put an emotional impulse under the behaviors and experiences that we map to the conscience. Mothering is the mother of all social relations and that would place the conscience in the social context. Natural philosophy would attribute the biological imperative to God and/or Nature as the ultimate source of cause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to feel guilt, remorse, etc etc about any number of things without their rights or wrongs having been explicitly taught to you. That doesn't mean the tendency to experience those emotions comes from a higher power- to me it seems much more natural to suppose they are the result of evolution.

Answer (score 1):

> Does guilt and conscience come from a higher source?

If you believe in a god or other higher source which created everything, then guilt and conscience are contained in "everything", and thus have been created by said god or higher source.

> Can someone have a conscience if they never were taught what was good from bad?

Yes, of course. People are generally able to figure out what is good or bad, right or wrong, more or less on their own, or at the very least extrapolating from earlier experiences, or from thinking very hard about it. Not everybody will come to the same conclusions, but that doesn't matter.

And no, I am of course not talking about some weird experiment where you isolate a human from birth and then somehow try to measure whether they experience guilt when they are an adult, never having met another person before; I am talking about normal, everyday stuff.

To quote Wikipedia:

> In common terms, conscience is often described as leading to feelings of remorse when a person commits an act that conflicts with their moral values.

Note "with *their* moral values". I assume that everybody does have moral values (where the exact details may of course vary wildly). Even the vilest mass murderer has moral values, which might deviate from yours or mine, but nevertheless are there and could lead to remorse (i.e., remorse about not having executed a particularly murder sloppily instead of according to their own standards of excellence).

We can easily imagine the worst dictators in history, having knowingly wrought immeasurable suffering on millions of humans, feel remorse in their last minutes about not having succeeded even more completely with their endeavors.

> Could they feel guilty without the education of what was right?

Sure. As an example take today's times where new things appear all the time. Few of our today's adults had an education of what is right or wrong regarding social media, AI or other modern-day features; and still people are generally capable to figure out what is right or wrong (not in a general sense quite yet, but on an individual level). Everybody will come to different conclusions, but once one has settled on an opinion of what is right, and subsequently infringes against that belief, can feel guilt.

> If so, does that mean that conscience could come from a higher source, such as God?

The question does not matter. If you believe in God, then everything comes from god, including conscience. If you do not believe in God, then the existence of conscience does not put you closer to believing in God. It is not hard to come up with completely natural explanations of how mechanisms like guilt and so on could have developed in humans; just like all the other society-related features of our brains.